# What's the logic that a Kosher Succah can lack a wall or two?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, sukkah

The Gemmorah in Succa (6-7) presents two views on the number of walls in a Kosher Succah - either 2 walls and a notch of 4 inches or 3 walls and a notch. Anyway, one or two walls can be largely missing.

I'm trying to comprehend the reason:

- If Succah is the remembrance of the Clouds G-d put us - there were 7 of them (6 of each side).
- If Succah is for the dwelling (תשבו כעין תדורו), such a place can't be called a house.
- If Succah is for the shadow alone - there's no need for walls altogether.

Besides attributing this fact to "Halocho leMoshe Misinai", is there a logical explanation for a Kosher Succah lacking a wall or two?

Comment: This isn't that different from a lean-to, which is a widely recognized and classic form of temporary basic dwelling

Comment: I'm saying "for the כען תדורו approach it is not dwelling" - nobody actually lives in a lean-to.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion:

The Gemara in the beginning of succa brings that a succa's function is to protect from wind and rain. The rain is protected from by the roof, which in order to not be a house has to be only partial protection. The protection from the wind does not require a wall in the direction opposite where the wind is coming from. Even two walls will suffice if the wind is directed at the closed corner.

About תשבו כעין תדורו, this pertains to how one dwells in the succa, and not to how the succa is constructed, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Cool idea! Did you come up with this yourself?

Comment: If I heard it I don't remember from whom, but it's been a long time since I heard shiur on Succa.

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding a citation and, if helpful, quotation of the particular line in the Gemara you're referring to.

Comment: 1. Can you find a source for "to protect from wind and rain", what it is learned from? 2. No, two walls will not suffice to protect from the winds. 3. It does not protect from the rain either - it should be designed not to protect from the rain in the first place!

Comment: The Gemara you’re thinking of is from Yeshaya 4:6. The passuk says a Sukkah is meant to (1) shade, protect from the heat; and (2) protect from storm and rain. My only problem with this is the Gemara on 6b uses this very passuk as a source for R’ Shimon that all four walls are required, but perhaps this is a valid answer according to the Chachamim. Your point about תשבו כעין תדורו seems to be the simplest understanding of 28b-29a, though perhaps Rava’s statement on 2a, that shorter permanent walls are kosher, may be problematic depending on how you read that.